# Google play store - can't install beta

Tags: android, deployment, google-play, google-play-services, android-keystore

I'm developing a new version of my Android application and I'd like to distribute a beta version to my testers. I created a group of private testers and then I uploaded my beta APK (more than 24 hours ago).
At this point I'm facing a strange behaviour:

- Google play store notified my app update only to my testers;
- When they try to update they get and error like: "Application cannot be installed because it's yet installed. Error code: -1"

I signed my APK with same keystore I previously used and I set an higher version of `versionCode` and `versionName`. App package is still the same.

Comment: What is the status of your uploaded new APK version? Is it "Update pending" or "Published"?

Comment: @noogui published. I tried on other devices and It works.

Comment: then it's a device issue? (it works on some and doesn't on others) or it coulde be that the email on the device you're using is not included in the list private testers